# Feasibility of an Empire with advanced ecological knowledge making Chott Melrhir a permanent lake?

Tags: science-based, alternate-reality, terraforming, medieval

**What is the feasibility of a North African based Roman Empire turning [Chott Melrhir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chott_Melrhir) into a permanent lake?**

The Empire has a population of around 8-10 millions, controls all of North Africa from Morocco to Tripoli in Libya and extends south to where the Atlas mountains descend into the Sahara. Ecology and water management have also their own independent research fields fully backed and institutionalized by the government. They do not have our level of pure scientific knowledge, but they are aware that legumes improve the soil, plants actually help contribute to a cooler and more humid environment, and lots of experience with earthworks like swales and check dams, etc. These fields have been institutionally backed for around a century and a half by this point.

Also the common farmer is quite educated in dryland farming and permaculture style techniques. So over the last century and a half there has also been a gradual expansion of water harvesting earthworks throughout the empire and the planting of nitrogen fixing plants and such throughout the empire.

My idea was that around the year 800 the empire has an ambitious and young emperor who wants a way to cement himself in history and improve the empire. Being aware that Chott Melrhir turns into a lake in heavy rainfall, he decides to try turning it and the surrounding lands into a new breadbasket for the empire. To do this, he has swales and check/brush dams built in all the wadis leading to Melrhir, along with planting Hardy desert trees to shade out the soil and wadis then planting nitrogen fixing plants and other good companion plants in the shade of said tree. Think Geoff Lawton's "greening the desert" approach. This is a long term project and it is known it will be.

Comment: You do understand this is a saline lake, right? How are you getting rid of all the salt?

Comment: I was indeed aware of that, I was thinking that maybe [Tamarix ramosissima] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamarix_ramosissima) could be used for slowly removing salt from the landscape, since salt collects in deposits on its branches farmers could take salty branches or just the deposit and use it or sell it, over time this would lower the salinity.

Comment: That seems like quite a stretch, but if you can reference some journals where they are using it to do just that, I'll be impressed. /the closest I was able to find was an article suggesting this might work from 2010.https://www.researchgate.net/publication/249074461_Salt_Separation_Processes_in_the_Saltcedar_Tamarix_ramosissima_Ledeb#:~:text=Citations%20(24)-,References%20(19),shoots%20%5B58%2C%2059%5D%20.  This sounds like it would take thousands of years, and new salt might enter the system faster than this highly invasive weed would take it out.

Comment: @DWKraus Dead Sea Salt farming is done by just scooping it up at the coast.

Comment: @Trish The goal here isn't producing salt, but somehow clearing the lake of enough salt to allow agriculture. I haven't heard of a successful attempt to reclaim any significant salt lake in this fashion. I don't just want to say no, if there's a way to do it. I'd want to see a reference first.

Comment: @DWKraus I wouldn't even *try* to desalt the lake, because it makes sense to keep the salt available in the climate!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [A] young emperor [...] wants a way to cement himself in history and improve the empire. Being aware that Chott Melrhir turns into a lake in heavy rainfall, he decides to try turning it and the surrounding lands into a new breadbasket for the empire. To do this, he has swales and check/brush dams built in all the wadis leading to Melrhir, along with planting Hardy desert trees to shade out the soil and wadis then planting nitrogen fixing plants and other good companion plants in the shade of said tree.

The project of the emperor is very commendable, but his ecological training in his schooling was lacking. However, the project does work, yet in a different way than he envisioned:

His engineers construct a series of Aquaeducts that deliver more freshwater from the mountains to the saline basin, managing to keep at least a small amount of water in it at all times. The basin itself turns into a very salty lake, akin to the Dead Sea. Directly at its borders, salines are constructed and people speak of the healing properties of bathing in the dammed-up waters.

The lake already is the reason for a triangle of somewhat green land south and east of it without the construction. This greenery will increase as the amount of water in the lake increases, though the salty ground will keep quite some of the water close. Now, the area might not become prime farming estates, but it will be good enough to support grass and having goats and smaller cattle there in much larger quantities than at the moment.

What started in the emperor's head as a project to farm the desert and rival Egypt, the real breadbasket of the Mediterranean, only one generation later turns the Sahel-like area into the meat basket of the empire, especially with the plentiful availability of salt from the lakes. The cattle's milk is turned into a cheese that, due to the procedure to make it with lots of salt and quite some pressing in underground cellars, is somewhat akin to hard Parmesan. Instead of being famed for grain, his name will be affixed to a certain kind of salted meat and a salty hard cheese from goat and sheep milk, which is quite transportable.

Comment: I never would have thought of this, a failed breadbasket becoming a dairy/meat basket. How plausible would that outcome be? Also if the Farmers in the area grow mainly halophytic plants as forage for the animals in the area would that help lower the salinity over time? even if on a scale of centuries.

Comment: Barely in the immediate area, but the effect of the lake being there is literally visible for hundreds of miles on satellite imaging already.